How to access local files saved via HTML 5 Filesystem API from chrome v3 extension?
My extension uses an old library, which is a wrapper over HTML 5 Filesystem API for managing local files.
This library creates a persistent storage with requested size. Storage files can be accessed via the chrome-extension://{extensionID}/ link.
But from my extension page, I cannot access those images inside of an <img/> elements.
Since manifest v3, Filesystem API cannot be used directly in of the service_worker process, I moved it to the offscreen page. It is working properly, files are being saved correctly, and they can be accessed and downloaded by the filesystem url (not from the page, but by url, they are being downloaded).
I also know that in manifest v3 you should describe web_accessible_resources inside of your manifest.json file: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/manifest/web-accessible-resources
So, this config part should probably look like that:
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        {
            "resources": ["persistent/*"],
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
        }
    ]

I did this, but still cannot access persisted local files. Can you help me out, where could I have made a mistake?
I know that one solution would probably be to convert icons and images to base64 format, but still want to consider other solutions.
UPD: can it be that I am not able to access those files because my extension is unpacked?

No need to answer this question anymore, I have found what the problem was and solved it. AS I said earlier, I have moved Filesystem Api usage to the offscreen page, at the same time, I didn't check the data I was sending through chrome.runtime.sendMessage. I was parsing favicons to blobs, and turned out that I needed to convert blobs to DataURL format before sending them to the offscreen.
